# tomi:upload Meteor package 503 service unavailable error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, meteor, imagemagick

I'm getting a 503 service unavailable error on production server using Tomi:upload package:

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

503 Service Unavailable @ 20.4 MB / sec
```

locally I have no problem and all the code works fine. Now I use MUP to deploy my app to a ubuntu with apache.

I use mup to log the errors as well:

```
/opt/dateanomad/.uploads//....E62FrDW7ifGkjieKC_bali.jpg

events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: spawn ENOENT
        at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #16
>> stepping down to gid: meteoruser  >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
```

I gave the /uploads and /uploads/tmp dirs chmod 777 rights, just.. for the sake of it.

The getFilename method works fine, but it's not writing different file versions (imageVersions method). imagemagick is installed.
I feel clueless. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
/server/init.js
UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/', 
    checkCreateDirectories: true,
    maxPostSize: 2500000, //2.5MB
    maxFileSize: 2500000, //2.5MB
    imageVersions: {
        bigPicture: {
            width: 800, 
            height: 600
        },
        thumbnailBig: {
            width: 300, 
            height: 300
        }, 
        thumbnailSmall: {
            width: 150, 
            height: 150
        }
    },
    getFileName: function(fileInfo, formData) {
    // rename file with userid_filename
    return formData.id +''+ fileInfo.name;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I feel really dumb for this.. but all I needed was a

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

I thought the node module was able to do the same, guess again.

Comment: Can you clarify more? I'm having a problem on how to resize image with this upload server

Comment: @Rasof In this case I didn't have imagemagick installed. I had a node module also called imagemagick, but that wasn't the module doing all the work is my guess. So after installing imagemagick this way, it all worked.